# Schema syntax different - why surround create table

Tags: mysql, sql

The normal examples I see for creating a table go like this:

```
CREATE TABLE supportContacts 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     type varchar(20), 
     details varchar(30)
    );
```

However an example I'm looking at does it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main`.`user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_password_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Specifically, on the create table like it is specifying the database and the new table and surrounding them in `` ` ``'s. What is the reasoning for this, and does one way have an advantage over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backticks are escape characters needed when identifiers contain special characters (such as spaces) or are reserved words (such as `group` or `order`).

Otherwise, they are not needed, and I do not think they are needed for any of the identifiers in this `create table` statement.

My personal preference is that over-use of escape characters is a bad thing:

- They make the query harder to read, because there are unnecessary characters everywhere.
- They make it harder to write the query.  I imagine the backtick key on people who do this alot starts to break.
- They encourage (or at least do not discourage) the use of "difficult" identifers.
- They make it more difficult to move code between databases.  (MySQL is one of the few databases that use backticks as an escape character.)

Of course, some people have different opinions on some of these points (although I think the second and fourth points are more truth than opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Backticks are used to escape table and column names.

You can do this to use keywords. If you want to name a column `from` for instance then you need the backticks. Otherwise the the DB interprets this a keyword.

Or if you want spaces in your table name like `my table` which BTW I recommend not to do.

In SQL Server you would use `[]` to escape the names.

Comment: Right ok, it doesn't seem necessary for things like "user_id" though is that right?

Comment: Exactly. But some people use them for a names. But that is totally up to you.